# Is there a way to index a list using a series without using loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, indexing

```
Result = pd.DataFrame({
'File': filenames_,
'Actual Classes': Actual_classes,
'Predicted Classes': Predicted_classes
})
Result.sample(frac = 0.02)
```

[image]

Actual Classes and Predicted Classes are integer values ranging from (1 to 8). I want to create a new column in the dataframe using the list of 9 strings:

```
['Black Sea Sprat', 'Gilt-Head Bream', 'Hourse Mackerel', 'Red Mullet',
 'Red Sea Bream', 'Sea Bass', 'Shrimp', 'Striped Red Mullet', 'Trout']
```

By indexing the values in df to the list without using a loop, rather by using the inbuilt pandas function.

I actually want a new column added to the dataframe using the list with indices corresponding to the row.
[image]

Comment: "Actual Classes and Predicted Classes are integer values ranging from (1 to 8)." Your image shows all zeros.

Comment: Why would you not use a loop?

Comment: how to use the list of 9 strings, what are the properties of the new column? Give a proper example of new column. Its vague

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @eroot163pi . I've added a new image showing how the new column is.
Taking first row as example, "Actual Class" is 1, so, we take first index of the list to get Class Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `apply`?

```py
classes = ['Black Sea Sprat', 'Gilt-Head Bream', 'Hourse Mackerel', 'Red Mullet',
 'Red Sea Bream', 'Sea Bass', 'Shrimp', 'Striped Red Mullet', 'Trout']

Result['class name'] = Result['Predicted Classes'].apply(lambda x: classes[x])
```